# Updating data points that have changed on invisble HighCharts series issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using HighCharts to show a graph containing a line and bar chart.  By default the bar series is not visible until you click the series header.  I have code that updates the bars on the fly but I have noticed that I cannot get existing information whilst the chart is invisible.

When I get data from the server I attempt to update any existing points, and add new ones if we have any.  This code works great if the series is visible, but if the series is not visible then `chart.series[1].data[idx]` returns `undefined`.  Clicking the series will show the chart so I know the data is there somewhere.  What am I doing wrong?

```
if (chart.series[1].data[idx] && chart.series[1].data[idx].y != inRate)
{   
    chart.series[1].data[idx].update(inRate);
    redraw = true;
}
else if (!chart.series[1].data[idx])
{
    var time = IntervalToTime(i, doorInterval);
    chart.series[1].addPoint([time, inRate], false, false);
    redraw = true;
}
```

After some investigation I made some progress. Apparently the data array isnt filled until the series has been visible at least once, so you cannot check for the data existence there. I found a processed data queue where data is held which seems to work but doing this method causes an error when attempting to call `chart.series[1].data[idx].update(inRate)`

```
if (chart.series[1].processedXData[idx] && chart.series[1].processedYData[idx] != inRate)
{
    chart.series[1].data[idx].update(inRate);
    redraw = true;
}
else if (!chart.series[1].processedXData[idx])
{
    var time = IntervalToTime(i, doorInterval);
    chart.series[1].addPoint([time, inRate], false, false);
    redraw = true;
}
```

Comment: Because of performance only visible points/series are updated, if you really need to update something try to update points directly in `series.options.data` (overwrite values in that array). Also, anykind of jsFiddle is always appreciated.

Comment: quick question, what does `inRate` represent in your question if you can cast your mind back? Also, was this code placed in a loop of the data points?

Comment: Hi `inRate` was basically my `Y` value, the chart was measuring flow or in rate.  Yes this was within a for loop

Comment: Thanks, having some bizarre issues with a chart where it renders data, then you swap the dataset to an empty dataset, it renders nothing, which I expect. But when I switch back to the original dataset, the chart renders empty. Yours is one of the many questions I've looked at so far.

Comment: Do you call redraw? (Just a thought)

Comment: @Chris Sorry about delay, didn't get notification on this. Yes calling redraw after reapplying series. The chart options seems to go corrupt in some way after binding to empty series. I've been trying to recreate the issue outside of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I found the issue.  Apparently the `data` array isnt filled until the series has been visible at least once, so you cannot check for the data existence there.  I found a processed data queue where data is held which seems to work.

```
if (chart.series[1].processedXData[idx] && chart.series[1].processedYData[idx] != inRate)
{
    chart.series[1].data[idx].update(inRate);
    redraw = true;
}
else if (!chart.series[1].processedXData[idx])
{
    var time = IntervalToTime(i, doorInterval);
    chart.series[1].addPoint([time, inRate], false, false);
    redraw = true;
}
```